# how to make http request for a array of values

Tags: angular, typescript

i need name of a car by requesting with id for an array of values. when i try to do that i got undefined http request,but i dont understand why it is happens ?
my code is .

```
 s = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
{
  this.s.forEach(function(v,index){

   this.http.get("http://127.1.1.0:5000/car/"+v)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
   this.car_name = data.name; // data[id:1,name:"BMW"]
   this.cars.push({
     "name":this.car_name
   })
   console.log(this.cars);
})
 }
```

what wrong in my code ?
"cannot read http of undefined" ,this is th error i got..any help  ?

Comment: You'll need to show the rest of your component, especially the constructor and any imports.

Comment: Replace  this.s.forEach(function(v,index){   WITH   this.s.forEach((v,index)=>{......

Comment: @brandon , my rest code is works,i tried it in postman,,,i think problem is in foreach..

Comment: @avij , i tried it gets error

Comment: What's your `rxjs` version

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.5.6",

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: so , the problem is in my map ?

Comment: it should not, see below the full version of code posted by @Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably losing the context of `this` because you are using `function()`. That is the reason `http` is undefined.

Instead, use fat arrow syntax `(() => {})` (ES6), which will maintain the context of `this`.

```
this.s.forEach((v,index) => {    
   this.http.get("http://127.1.1.0:5000/car/"+v)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
         this.car_name = data.name; // data[id:1,name:"BMW"]
         this.cars.push({
            "name":this.car_name
         })
         console.log(this.cars);
    });
})
```